# For positive integer $n$, find $f(4)$ from the given expression

Tags: trigonometry

> For positive integers $n$ let $$f(n)=\frac {\sum_{k=0}^n \sin \left(\frac{k+1}{n+2} \pi\right) \sin\left( \frac{k+2}{n+2} \pi\right)}{\sum_{k=0}^n \sin^2 \left(\frac{k+1}{n+2}\pi\right)}$$ Find $f(4)$.

Re writing the numerator

$$\frac 12 [\cos \frac{-1}{n+2}\pi -\cos \frac{2k+3}{n+2}\pi]$$

And the denominator

$$1-\cos^2 \frac{k+1}{n+2} \pi$$

So the expression is

$$\frac{(n+1)\cos \frac{1}{n+2} \pi  -\sum \cos \frac{2k+3}{n+2}\pi}{2[(n+1)-\sum \cos^2 \frac{k+1}{n+2}\pi]}$$

I don’t know how to apply the summation operator to the cosine terms. How should it be done?

Comment: How is $f$ defined?

Comment: Can’t you just plug in $n=1$ and evaluate manually?

Comment: @Tavish there are a number of questions in relation to this, including ones such that $f(4)$ and $f(n)$. Simplification is the only way to go for this

Comment: @Integrand the given expression is the function $f(n)$